# Finding the size of int [] array

Tags: c++

In the following function, how can we find the length of the array

```
int fnLenghthOfArray(int arry[]){
    return sizeof(arry)/sizeof(int); // This always returns 1
}
```

Here this function always returns 1.
Where as, `sizeof(arry)/sizeof(int)` gives the actual length of the array, in the function where it is declared.

If we use vector or template like

```
template<typename T,int N> 

int fnLenghthOfArray(T (&arry)[N]){

}
```

we can get the size. But here I am not allowed to change the function prototype.

Please help me to find this.

Comment: If you're not allowed to modify the function's prototype then I don't think that's possible...

Comment: Passing array as arguments makes it pointer to its first element.You need to pass length of array as argument too.

Comment: The template includes `int N`. Is that N intended to be the array length?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember, in C when you pass an array as an argument to a function, you're passing a **pointer** to the array. If you want to pass the size of the array, you should pass it as a separated argument.

The size of a pointer and an `int` is 4 or 8 or something else - depending on `ABI`.
In your case, it's `4`, so you're getting `sizeof(int *)/sizeof int` which is 1.

---

**Here is a useful trick**

You can store the length of the array in the first element of it:

```
int myArray[]= {-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
myArray[0] = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]) - 1;
//The -1 because.. the first element is only to indicate the size
```

Now, `myArray[0]` will contain the size of the array.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your valuable answers.
I know why return sizeof(arry)/sizeof(int); always return 1.

But in some online contexts I used to get a function prototype like this and need to write code inside.

Comment: Those contexts are broken. If you need the length, you have to pass it in (or use the template trick you already know).

Answer (score 3):

In function decalration, `array` is a pointer:

```
int fnLenghthOfArray(int arry[])
                        ^
                          is same as int* array
```

And in your system `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Don't you mean the size of `int *`, rather than `void *`?

Comment: @Hasturkun that doesn't matter, pointers just store addresses, their size depend only on the CPU architecture.

Comment: @Hasturkun actually I written this because `sizeof(void*)`   == `sizeof(any pointer)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's not necessarily true. There are architectures where `sizeof(char*) > sizeof(int*)`, which also means `sizeof(void*) > sizeof(int*)`. The only thing the standard guarantees if `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(T*)` for any object type `T`.

Comment: @Angew I am unaware of this. then I should updated answer. Thanks Angew!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan To give some more concrete info, for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3153244/1782465) mentions such an architecture.

Comment: @Angew  Yes Angew  Just read it. till now I know that size of pointers are same except function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You function declaration

```
int fnLenghthOfArray(int arry[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int fnLenghthOfArray(int* arry);
```

hence your calculation yields 1 (based on the assumption that the size of a pointer to int and size of an int are the same).

Your only option to get the size of the array is to provide an additional parameter

```
int fnLenghthOfArray(int arry[], std::size_t size);
```

Alternatively you could use one of the C++ containers like `vector` or `array`

Answer (score 1):

```
int fnLenghthOfArray(int arry[]){
    return sizeof(arry)/sizeof(int); // This always returns 1
}
```

This function returns 1 because is performing a division between the size of a pointer and  the size of an integer. In most architectures, the size of a pointer is equal to the size of an integer. For instance, in the `x86` architecture both have size 4 bytes.

> Where as, sizeof(arry)/sizeof(int) gives the actual length of the
>   array, in the function where it is declared

Because in this case the compiler knows that `arry` is an array and its size. Whereas, in the previous function, the compiler knows `arry` only as a pointer. In fact, when you specify the function prototype, there is not difference between `int arry[]` and `int * arry`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int arry[]
```

is equivalent to

```
int *arry
```

and the *sizeof()* operator returns 4 when applied to *arry* because it's the size of a pointer (or reference in the case of arry[]), the size of the int is also 4 bytes and that's why it always returns 1.

To solve your problem you must implement the array in a different way. Maybe the first element should always have the size of the array. Otherwise you could use the *vector* class from STL or *list*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get size of array in `C` or `C++`.

Array in this languages is simply pointer to first element. You need to keep size of array by yourself.

Comment: why there is no method like size() in java present in c or c++ language?

Comment: "You can't get size of array in C or C++.", wrong, `sizeof array` will give you the size of the array. "Array in this languages is simply pointer to first element.", wrong, you confuse pointer and array.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is code snippet using Maroun's trick.**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print_array(int *array);
void shift_array_normal(int *array,int arrayLen);

int main(void)
{
    int array[]= {-1,32,44,185,28,256,22,50};
    array[0] = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) - 1;

    print_array(array);
    return 0;
}

void print_array(int *array){
 int index,arrayLen = array[0];

 //length of array is stored in arrayLen now we can convert array back.
 printf("Length of array is : %d\n",arrayLen);

 //convert array back to normal.
 shift_array_normal(array,arrayLen);

 //print int array .
 for(index = 0; index < arrayLen; index++)
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n",index,array[index]);
}

/*removing length element from array and converting it back to normal array*/
void shift_array_normal(int *array,int arrayLen){
    int index;

    for(index = 0; index < arrayLen; index++)
     array[index] = array[index + 1];       
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[300];

    int d = sizeof(array)/4;
    std::cout<<d;   
}
```

Use:

```
// sizeof(array)/4  for "int" array reserves 4 bits.
// sizeof(array)/4  for "float" array reserves 4 bits.
// sizeof(array)    for "char" array reserves 2 bits.
// sizeof(array)    for "bool" array reserves 2 bits.
// sizeof(array)/8  for "double" array reserves 8 bits.
// sizeof(array)/16 for "long double" array reserves 16 bits.
```